# How can I get the name of an automatically-created Heroku instance?

Tags: heroku, codeship

When an integrated service, like CodeShip CI, runs tests, an instance is spun-up on Heroku to run the CI suite.

How can I get the name of that branch/build-specific Heroku app, in a programmatic manner?

**My use case:** I want to give a developer heroku-cli access to the staging instance that was spun-up for their branch. Also, I want the instance URL so that QA can check it for accuracy.

---

I don't know if this is principally a *CodeShip* question, or a *Heroku* question.  I can solve the rest of the integration, if I simply can get the name/info for this new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeship [defines certain environment variables with each run](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-integration/set-environment-variables/#default-environment-variables).

Thus I can build a URL based on all of the known pieces, per env:

```
app_name = 'foo'
env      = 'staging'

name_parts = [
  app_name,
  env,
  'pr'
  ENV['CI_BUILD_NUMBER']
]

testing_url = 'http://' + name_parts.join('-') + '.herokuapp.com'
#=> foo-staging-pr-2729.herokuapp.com

send_to_chatroom(app_name + '_dev_notification')
```